# Problem with edges using the displace modifier

Tags: modifiers, displacement, height-map

I've gone through other peoples' questions and could not find an answer to the following problem: When using a height map with the displace modifier I get 2 neat edges and 2 bad edges that sort of plunge down. (everything but the edges is entirely fine) in the image there are 2 tiles, each with a different height map, I cut them exactly so that they connect seamlessly when side by side, and the bad edges obviously ruin that effect.

So far I've tried to have the mesh be split into the same number of faces as there are pixels in the height map, thinking maybe that proportion is important, that did not fix the problem.

I've also tried tweaking the texture settings, changing the mapping settings did not solve the problem. it is worth noting that the edges that plunge should be displaced, when I crop them out, there is a missing link between the two tiles I'm connecting.

[image]

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Would really appreciate some help on this too. For me I fond it's always the top edge and the right most edge that protrude sharply backwards. I have tried altering my UVs but this just breaks the tiling.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered in the texture properties of the height map, under mapping, extension, mine was set to clip. When I changed it to repeat, this fixed the issue for me. I hope this helps.